# Remove the icon of windows software from ubuntu search panel

Tags: wine, software-center

I have installed a WinRAR (a windows software) using wine which created an icon of WinRAR on ubuntu search panel. But afterwards i uninstalled the wine software through ubuntu software center. But the icon of WinRAR is still on the ubuntu search panel. Please guide me how to remove it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why did you have the need to install windows rar software when you can just install p7zip-full and unrar from repositories?

Comment: building on what @xangua wrote, you could uninstall the WinRAR and install `p7zip-full` and `unrar`.  I'm not aware of any WinRAR features you will miss. I'm not sure how to remove just the icons. Maybe you'll be able to find a WinRAR.desktop file. If you delete that and restart your system, you should be good to go. But i'm not sure if  this works in wine...